# Unable to destroy activity - null pointer

Tags: android

I am getting this message.  My entry activity calls another activity which displays it's own view and sets an alarm.   As a user I then use the back button of the emulator to step back through the views and return to the emulator general front screen.  It is then that I get the above error.   The app code has worked ok until today and the only thing I have done is to rem out the Google App licensing code while I test.   Any ideas as to where I should staart looking?

Also where do I find the trace file generated when I run the emulator in debug mode?   Logcat show the error message but not all the preceing trace referecnes - just says ... 11 more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method here is to run your app in the Debug configuration and try to get the line of code in question into the debugger somehow.

If the debugger isn't triggered automatically by your NullPointerException, then you could try setting breakpoints in the `onDestroy` methods of your activities and step through until you hit the exception.

Once you isolated the problem, you could post the code here if the fix isn't obvious.